# Bash run previous command with all arguments without last

Tags: bash

I often do something like this:

```
php artisan route:list
php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed
```

Only artisan command name is changed. I know how to get all parameters of previous command except last: `!:1-` (in my case it gives me `artisan`). But maybe exist shortcut that gives me command name with all arguments except last (in my case `php artisan`)? I know I can use `alias a="php artisan"` for such purpose, but general shortcut for any command will be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same trick applies, just change 1 to 0

```
!:0-
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a function?  I called it `rms` for `route; migrate; seed`

```
rms () { php "$1" "route:list"; php "$1" migrate; php "$1" "db:seed"; }
```